# Error in Sublime Text while opening .blade.php

Tags: laravel, sublimetext3, laravel-blade

When I open the Sublime Text editor all text colors go white and there is no exact font color tag wise.

Error while opening sublime text editor:

```
Error loading syntax file "Packages/Laravel Blade 
Highlighter/blade.sublime-syntax": Apparent recursion within a 
with_prototype action: 25000 context sanity limit hit
```

Comment: thanks @Troyer it's working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same problem few days ago, and I [found there is a solution](https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade/issues/137#issuecomment-318932076); a CSS 3 package is making trouble working with the Laravel Blade Highlighter package. You should disable the CSS 3 package with `Package Control: Disable Package CSS3` on the command palette, restart Sublime Text, and then it will work as expected.

There you can read the comment:

> Hi, I'm the author of CSS3. I was able to reproduce the issue when
>   both the default CSS package and CSS3 were enabled. I recommend
>   disabling the default CSS package in my install notes, but I
>   understand that many people can't do that because they use a package
>   that depends on the default CSS package (like Laravel Blade).
>
> The clumsy workaround is to **enable/disable CSS and CSS3. When you're
>   working on blade files**, you can Package Control: Disable Package CSS3
>   and enable CSS. If you're working primarily with pure CSS files, I
>   recommend disabling CSS and enabling CSS3.
>
> Sorry, I know that's an awkward solution. If I think of something
>   better, I'll post it here.